# Google plus button not working correctly in wordpress / FF when >1 button per page

Tags: wordpress, google-plus

I have google plus buttons beside the excerpts on my Wordpress website homepage and archive pages.

I'm using the google plus button code from Google's site:

">

The google plus button only appears beside the first post on the page in Firefox.
It works fine in Chrome.

Any ideas why this would happen? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to troubleshoot your issue without seeing some code, but here are a few things I'd check for:

- Are you sourcing the plusone.js file more than once? If so, only source it once in a single  element.
- Do you see any errors on your JavaScript console? If so those probably shed some light on why the buttons beyond your first one are not rendering.

OK, that's only two things. Hopefully this helps anyway :)